# How to NOT delete a war directory on Jetty server stop()

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am trying to create a "warless" (exploded war, war directory only) deployment of embedded Jetty. I have been able to make it run by passing the path to the war folder to the WebAppContext(...) constructor and making sure that extractWAR, copyWebDir and CopyWebInf are set to false. I do not set a temp directory.

This runs fine. However, after stopping this, the content of the war folder is deleted and replaced with  just one empty subfolder - jsp. So, next time this runs there is nothing there to run... and that is the problem.

I would ideally also like to keep any JSP compilation artifacts in place (for various reasons I am not doing build-time precompiled JSPs .... yet).

Does anyone know what causes this? I am assuming Jetty believes that this is a temp folder and that it should be removed... but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause. Something else was setting the temp folder to the same path as the exploded war. Once I changed that to a different folder the deletion no longer happened.

That still leaves my other question though... but I'll live with it.